# Montar página dinamicamente com PHP

Tags: php

Preciso exibir diferentes páginas conforme um valor que vem pela URI, fiz este código, não está apontando erros, mas também não exibe o conteúdo do h1.

```
<?php
  require_once"cabecalho.php";
  $plano = $_GET['plano'];
  if($plano == 'parcial'){ ?>
    <section class="plano-parcial">
      <h1>Plano parcial detalhes</h1>
    </section>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Coloque esses comandos antes do `require_once` e veja se algum erro irá aparecer. 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Da um `var_dump()` em `$plano` antes do `if()` pra ver qual o valor dessa variável, pode ser um erro de comparação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque esses comandos antes do `require_once` e veja se algum erro irá aparecer.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Creio que o seu `require_once` está falhando, mas você não está setado para exibir erros e/ou notices. Essa é a única possibilidade de não mostrar o seu `H1` no seu código, além do óbvio (creio que não seja isso) de não estar passando 'parcial' no seu `GET`